# YAML indentation problem in "each" loop in AzureDevops pipline

Tags: loops, azure-devops, yaml, indentation

got a trouble with indentation problem (I guess). The code is like this:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  bl_layer: $[eq(variables['bl_version'], '')]
  blbsm_layer: $[eq(variables['blbsm_version'], '')]

parameters:
- name: 'layer'
  type: object
  default:
    - bl
    - blbsm


- name: Cluster
  values: 
    - Sit-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-test-1635527241795


- name: namespace
  values:
    - sap-test

steps:
  - ${{ each p in parameters.layer }}: 
        - task: Kubernetes@1
          condition: ne(variables.${{p}}_layer, 'true')
          displayName: Running on ${{p}}
          inputs:
            connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
            kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '${{ parameters.cluster }}'
            namespace: '${{ parameters.namespace }}'
            command: 'set'
            arguments: 'image deployment/${{p}} ${{p}}=xxxx.azurecr.io/gpf/${{p}}:$(${{p}}_version)'
```

In result, for each value in 'layer' parameter, it should inject image version in deployment (listed in 'leyer' section).
In 'bl' deployment all goes ok, but in 2nd interation 'blbsm' it will leave blank version. If I test it with yaml validation tool it will give indication that there is a indetation problem here:

```
      image: 'gjcststacr.azurecr.io/gpf/blbsm:44.100.28.03
```

What can be the cause of issue?
Thanks in advance!

I have tried:

- run separate loops for 'layers' (namespaces) - in separation it works
- lint yaml file for both 'layers' - indication issue in 2nd run

Comment: Why does it seem like the `- task:` list member is indented with 4 spaces when the rest of the file is indented with 2 spaces? Can you try indenting your `each` loop as seen in these docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#containsvalue?

Comment: Please add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline. After that trigger a new pipeline and check what's the value of `arguments` in the debug logs.